# Augmented Reality iOS application tracking issue

Tags: ios, opencv, opengl-es, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I am able to detect markers, identify markers and initialise OpenGL objects on screen. The issue I'm having is overlaying them on top of the markers position in the camera world. My camera is calibrated best I can using this method [Iphone 6 camera calibration for OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963337/iphone-6-camera-calibration-for-opencv). I feel there is an issue with my cameras projection matrix, I create it as follows:

```
-(void)buildProjectionMatrix:
     (Matrix33)cameraMatrix: 
     (int)screen_width:  
     (int)screen_height: 
     (Matrix44&) projectionMatrix
 {
 float near = 0.01;  // Near clipping distance
 float far  = 100;  // Far clipping distance

// Camera parameters
float f_x = cameraMatrix.data[0]; // Focal length in x axis
float f_y = cameraMatrix.data[4]; // Focal length in y axis 
float c_x = cameraMatrix.data[2]; // Camera primary point x
float c_y = cameraMatrix.data[5]; // Camera primary point y

std::cout<<"fx "<<f_x<<" fy "<<f_y<<" cx "<<c_x<<" cy "<<c_y<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"width "<<screen_width<<" height "<<screen_height<<std::endl;

projectionMatrix.data[0] = - 2.0 * f_x / screen_width;
projectionMatrix.data[1] = 0.0;
projectionMatrix.data[2] = 0.0;
projectionMatrix.data[3] = 0.0;

projectionMatrix.data[4] = 0.0;
projectionMatrix.data[5] = 2.0 * f_y / screen_height;
projectionMatrix.data[6] = 0.0;
projectionMatrix.data[7] = 0.0;

projectionMatrix.data[8] = 2.0 * c_x / screen_width - 1.0;
projectionMatrix.data[9] = 2.0 * c_y / screen_height - 1.0;
projectionMatrix.data[10] = -( far+near ) / ( far - near );
projectionMatrix.data[11] = -1.0;

projectionMatrix.data[12] = 0.0;
projectionMatrix.data[13] = 0.0;
projectionMatrix.data[14] = -2.0 * far * near / ( far - near );
projectionMatrix.data[15] = 0.0;
}
```

This is the method to estimate the position of the marker:

```
void MarkerDetector::estimatePosition(std::vector<Marker>& detectedMarkers)
{
for (size_t i=0; i<detectedMarkers.size(); i++)
{                   
    Marker& m = detectedMarkers[i];

    cv::Mat Rvec;
    cv::Mat_<float> Tvec;
    cv::Mat raux,taux;
    cv::solvePnP(m_markerCorners3d, m.points, camMatrix, distCoeff,raux,taux);
    raux.convertTo(Rvec,CV_32F);
    taux.convertTo(Tvec ,CV_32F);

    cv::Mat_<float> rotMat(3,3); 
    cv::Rodrigues(Rvec, rotMat);

    // Copy to transformation matrix
    for (int col=0; col<3; col++)
    {
        for (int row=0; row<3; row++)
        {        
            m.transformation.r().mat[row][col] = rotMat(row,col); // Copy rotation component
        }
        m.transformation.t().data[col] = Tvec(col); // Copy translation component
    }

    // Since solvePnP finds camera location, w.r.t to marker pose, to get marker pose w.r.t to the camera we invert it.
    m.transformation = m.transformation.getInverted();
}
}
```

The OpenGL shape is able to track and account for size and roation, but something is going wrong with the translation. If the camera is turned 90 degrees, the opengl shape swings around 90 degrees about the centre of the marker. Its almost as if I am translating before rotating, but I am not.

See video for issue:

https://vid.me/fLvX

Comment: afaik `Since solvePnP finds camera location, w.r.t to marker pose, to get marker pose w.r.t to the camera we invert it.` is wrong. Instead solvePnP finds the object location for a constant camera pose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have some problem with projecting the 3-D modelpoints. Essentially, `solvePnP` gives a transformation that brings points from the model coordinate system to the camera coordinate system and this is composed of a rotation and translation vector (output of `solvePnP`):

```
cv::Mat rvec, tvec;
cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec)
```

At this point you are able to project model points onto the image plane

```
std::vector<cv::Vec2d> imagePointsRP; // Reprojected image points
cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePointsRP);
```

Now, you should only draw the points of `imagePointsRP` over the incoming image and if the pose estimation was correct then you'll see the reprojected corners over the corners of the marker

Anyway, the matrices of model TO camera and camera TO model direction can be composed as below:

```
cv::Mat rmat
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rmat); // mRmat is 3x3

cv::Mat modelToCam = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
modelToCam(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(0, 3)) = rmat * 1.0;
modelToCam(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(3, 4)) = tvec * 1.0;

cv::Mat camToModel = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
cv::Mat rmatinv = rmat.t();  // rotation of inverse
cv::Mat tvecinv = -rmatinv * tvec; // translation of inverse

camToModel(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(0, 3)) = rmatinv * 1.0;
camToModel(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(3, 4)) = tvecinv * 1.0;
```

In any case, it's also useful to estimate reprojection error and discard the poses with high error (remember, the PnP problem has only unique solution if n=4 and these points are coplanar):

```
double totalErr = 0.0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < imagePoints.size(); i++)
{
    double err = cv::norm(cv::Mat(imagePoints[i]), cv::Mat(imagePointsRP[i]), cv::NORM_L2);
    totalErr += err*err;
}

totalErr = std::sqrt(totalErr / imagePoints.size());
```

Comment: I found the issue eventually, it was an initialisation issue with my calibration data. I thank you for your informative response, it has taught me to record the reprojection error!